# Importing & saving a file to a NOSQL Database with Python

Tags: python, database, nosql, save

I need to save a file to a NoSQL Database using python. Which libraries could be useful/ how should I go about this?

Comment: Very broad question, answer depends on which NoSQL database.

Comment: @RavishankarSivasubramaniam lets say I was to use a MongoDB?

Answer (score 0):

There is no single standard driver for NoSql databases. Most NoSql database have native python driver and other 3rd party driver.

For MongoDB : Pymongo is the native python library/driver.

Monogoengine is a good option if you are looking for something like an orm.